# Android - BroadcastReceiver EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_ERROR missing

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, state

I have this BroadcastReceiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiverWifi = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction() == WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION) {
                int error = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_ERROR, -1);

}
```

In Android 4.1.2, 4.4.2 works but in Android 4.0.3 always return -1 (when the passwork is wrong)